# Concrete steps for testng report using listener

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for concrete steps  to customized the report by using ITestListener interface & TestListenerAdapter class methods following two methods.

Where to change in the following resources?

```
@override
onTestfailure( ITestResult tr)
{
 log("Failed");
}

@override
onTestSuccess( ITestResult tr)
{
 log("Passed");
}
```

1-Test Class

```
public class Mytest()
{
 @Parameters({ "first-name" })  
 @Test 
 public void testSingleString(String firstName) {   
  System.out.println("Invoked testString " + firstName);  
  assert "xxx".equals(firstName);  
 } 
}
```

2- testng.xml

```
<suite>
<listeners>
</listeners>
<parameter name="first-name"  value="xxx"/> 
<test name="MyTest">
<classes>  
<class name="example1.Mytest"/>  
</classes>  
</test> 
</suite>
```

Note: I run my testng eclipse using Run As TestNg.

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the listener class in the xml.

```
<suite>
<listeners>
<listener class-name="packagename.classname.which contains ontestfailure and success"/>
</listeners>
<parameter name="first-name"  value="xxx"/> 
<test name="MyTest">
<classes>  
<class name="example1.Mytest"/>  
</classes>  
</test> 
</suite>
```